# Copy ALL data To clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard

I am trying to write code for a simple note taker app for work, but struggling with code to copy all fields to clipboard.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>NOTEPAD 1.0</h2>


<form>
<div class="notes">

<form id="form1">


<label for="name"><b>Name:</b></label><br>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>

<label for="AR"><b>AR#:</b></label><br>
<input type="text" id="AR" name="AR"><br>

<label for="Verified"><b>Verified:</b></label><br>
<input type="text" id="Verified" name="Verified"><br>

<label for="Reason"><b>Reason:</b></label><br>
<input type="text" id="Reason" name="Reason"><br>

<label for="Resolution"><b>Resolution:</b></label><br>
<div>
<textarea style="width:700px; height: 200px;"></textarea></div>


<script>
let name = document.getElementById(name).value
let nameLabel = "Name:\t"
let ARLabel = "AR#:\t"
let copyString = nameLabel.concat(name, '\n', ARLabel, "AR");
</script>
<button onclick="navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyString)">Copy</button>

<input type="reset">

<p>
```

I want the copy output to display as

Name:
AR#:
Verified:
Reason:
Resolution:

Once copy button is pressed it will clipboard the labels and all of the input fields